# How to listen when a ChildComponent changes and then execute a method in the ParentComponent?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I'm looking for a clean and efficient solution in Angular 7 to execute a method in a component every time a child component changes.

Given a `ParentComponent` rendering a `ChildComponent`, I need to know when the `ChildComponent` was changed and then execute the function in the `ParentComponent`.

By change I'm referring to changes in the view or in any property in the Child class.

Thanks.

Comment: The ChildComponent is provided dynamically and having an @Input to be called is not an option. It's has to be transparent for the child component.

Answer (score 3):

[Prettyfly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884297/how-to-listen-when-a-childcomponent-changes-and-then-execute-a-method-in-the-par/54884352#54884352) seams acceptable, but there is the alternative of a service.

I find this [link](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) quite descriptive.

Create an observable(ex. [RXJS's subject](https://coryrylan.com/blog/rxjs-observables-versus-subjects)) in the service and subscribe to it at your parent component, so as to keep track of its changes and handle them accordingly.

At the dynamically created component, in onChanges lifecycle hook or in any action based function, you can trigger the observable to emit changes (which then the parent/any other subscriber will 'listen' through the subscription)

Just remember to provide the service in the parent component, so as the parent and its children share the same service instance, or in app.module to make it global for the whole app.

Services also enable biderictional data sharing among parent, child and sibling components.

EDIT: In case you don't use `<ng-template>` and component is created on the fly, you can manually detect its changes by passing its reference to 'componentRef' and calling `componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();`

Answer (score 2):

Create an `EventEmitter` in the child component, and emit when it changes.

Subscribe to the event-emitter from the parent component's template, and execute your function each time it emits.

e.g

**parent.component.html**

```
<child-component (changeEmitter)="executeParentFunction()"> </child-component>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Output() changeEmitter: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

ngOnChanges() {
    this.changeEmitter.emit(true);
}
```

> The ChildComponent is provided dynamically and having an @Input to be called is not an option. It's has to be transparent for the child component.

This will still apply. As long as the **child** component is the one in control of emitting on change, then any parent can subscribe to it, even when dynamically added.

Comment: Also note, the `EventEmitter` type doesn't need to be boolean. Just personal preference, as you're not actually using the emitted value. That said, using `boolean` allows you to be more selective in your `ngOnChanges`, and only emit true when your child change meets any criteria you choose - then your parent function may want to only execute when `true` is emitted.

Comment: Thanks. That was my first try. Unfortunately doesn't work for me. I'm looking to integrate with ngTemplateOutlet, where I don't know the specification of the child component (could be any component). Let's take as example a DialogComponent, where you render any dynamic component. Still, I need to know when the dynamic component changes. Is that makes sense?